# GCDASyncScocket readDataToLength: with swift

Tags: swift, network-programming, gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to implement an app using GCDAsynSocket framework with Swift. I am stuck at GCDASyncSocket's readDataToLength method.

In objective c, we use to write it as following:

```
    [socket readDataToLength:sizeof(uint64_t) withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];
```

Now, I am not sure how can I replace sizeof(uint64_t) in Swift.

Comment: Removed fluff and blatantly inappropriate tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost similar in Swift, but unlike (Objective-)C, there are different keywords
for taking the size of a *type:*

```
let size = sizeof(UInt64)
```

or  the size of a *value:*

```
var x : UInt64 = 0
let size = sizeofValue(x)
```

Comment: It did not work, I keep getting this error: /Users/Vikramjeet/Desktop/MPSocketTest/MPSocketTest/ViewController.swift:81:19: Cannot invoke 'readDataToLength' with an argument list of type '(Int, withTimeout: $T5, tag: IntegerLiteralConvertible)'       . It seems to work if I replace size with an int like 1024. any ideas?

Comment: @VikSingh: You have to look up the exact type of each parameter, and then convert the arguments to that type, for example `UInt(sizeof(UInt64))`.

Comment: Ofcourse. Thanks a lot it worked. I am still not used to these Swift errors.